# Targeting a specific div for Bootstrap 3 Modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I've been reading all morning but .. I'm stuck. I'm trying to load a Bootstrap modal with content from another page on my site (same domain). It's kind of working, but the modal loads the whole page, not just the content I need. I need a way of targeting a specific div, so it doesn't load everything.

Some background - The site uses Smarty, and each page is attached to a main layout. So the modal is loading side bar menus etc I don't want. This other page I need content from has Smarty tags that only work on it's own specific page so I'm unable to move the script/content to the same page as the modal script (The tags won't load).

Here's what I have so far;

Button;

```
 <a data-toggle="modal" href="{$file_name}?a=cart&amp;action=new&amp;main_type=listing_edit&amp;listing_id={$listing.id}" data-target="#edit"><img src="{external file='images/buttons/listing_edit.gif'}" alt="{$messages.509}" /></a>
```

Modal;

```
  <div class="modal fade in" id="edit" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">

        <div class="modal-header">
            <h3 class="modal-title"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>Edit My Listing</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <p class="page_instructions">Loading...</p>
        </div>

        <div class="modal-footer"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The page the modal gets content from;

```
<div class="modal-header">
    <h3 class="modal-title"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>{$messages.482}</h3>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
    <p class="page_instructions">{$messages.483}</p>

    {if $error_msgs.cart_error}
        <div class="field_error_box">
            {$error_msgs.cart_error}
        </div>
    {/if}

    <div class="center">
        <ul class="button_list">
            {foreach from=$choices item=label key=step}
                <li>
                    <a href="{$nextPage}&amp;doStep={$step}" class="btn-block btn-u btn-brd btn-brd-hover rounded btn-u-blue btn-u-sm margin-bottom-5">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-3"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></div>
                                <div class="col-md-6"><span>{$label}</span></div>
                                <div class="col-md-3"></div>
                            </div>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    {/foreach}
                </ul>

                <div class="clr"><br /></div>

                <ul class="button_list">
                    <li><a href="{$previewUrl}" onclick="window.open(this.href,'previewWindow','scrollbars=yes,status=no,width=800,height=600'); return false;" class="btn-block btn-u btn-brd btn-brd-hover rounded btn-u-orange btn-u-sm margin-bottom-5">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-3"><i class="fa fa-file-text-o"></i></div>
                                <div class="col-md-6"><span>{$messages.500483}</span></div>
                                <div class="col-md-3"></div>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="{$cart_url}&amp;action=cancel" class="btn-block btn-u btn-brd btn-brd-hover rounded btn-u-red btn-u-sm margin-bottom-5">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-3"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></div>
                                <div class="col-md-6"><span>{$messages.500257}</span></div>
                                <div class="col-md-3"></div>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>

                <div class="clr"><br /></div>
            </div>  
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <ul class="button_list center">
                <li><a href="{$nextPage}&amp;doStep=continue" class="btn-block btn-u btn-brd btn-brd-hover rounded btn-u-green btn-u-sm">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-3"><i class="fa fa-check"></i></div>
                            <div class="col-md-6"><span>{$messages.500256}</span></div>
                            <div class="col-md-3"></div>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>

            <div class="clr"><br /></div>
        </div>
```

Comment: separating the modal into separate file and include using `php include` everywhere you need it. Than you can just reference it by id

Comment: Thanks Said Kholov, This is a classifieds site and the data on this page I want to load into the Modal is dynamic/ changes depending on the listing. If I put the Modal into a PHP file and then include it, the tags won't load.

Comment: I think it needs to stay where it is, and I need to figure out a way to target just the info listed above

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the best approach but it will work:

```
$(function(){

    $.get('http://dodsoftware.com/sotests/get_test/content.html', function(result){
         var otherPageBody=result.match(/<body>([\s\S]+)<\/body>/)[1];
         var $otherPageBody=$('<div>'+otherPageBody+'<\div>');
         var targetContent = $otherPageBody.find('#target-content')[0].outerHTML;
         $('.result').append(targetContent);
    });

});
```

#### [Here is a working example](http://dodsoftware.com/sotests/get_test/)

Note that you'll want to add some checks in there to avoid errors if the content is not found.